# What am I doing wrong while populating this UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uitableviewdatasourceprefetching

I am trying to populate a UITableView using an array and I am unable to do so. Here is what I have so far. This code is for retrieving data and storing it in the array that I am using to populate the UITableView:

```
func prepareForRetrieval() {
        Database.database().reference().child("UserCart").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).observe(.value, with: {
            (snapshot) in
            for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects {
                let id = snap as! DataSnapshot
                self.keyArray.append(id.key)
            }
            self.updateCart()
        })
    }
func updateCart() {
        for key in keyArray {
            Database.database().reference().child("UserCart").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let itemName = value?["Item Name"] as! String
                let itemPrice = value?["Item Price"] as! Float
                let itemQuantity = value?["Item Quantity"] as! Int
                self.cartArray.append(CartData(itemName: itemName, itemQuantity: itemQuantity, itemPriceNumber: itemPrice))
                print(self.cartArray.count)
            })
        }
    }
```

The data is properly appending into the array and when I print the count of the array, it prints the correct count. This means that the data is there. However, when I try to populate a UITableView, it doesn't detect any data. I have the following code to make sure that there is data in the array before trying to populate the UITableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cartBrain.prepareForRetrieval()

        if cartBrain.cartArray.isEmpty == false{
            tableViewOutlet.dataSource = self
            tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
        }
        else {
            tableViewOutlet.isHidden = true
            tableViewOutlet.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            purchaseButtonOutlet.isEnabled = false
            cartEmptyLabel.text = "Your cart is empty. Please add items and check back later."
        }
}
```

When I open the View Controller, the TableView is disabled because it doesn't detect any data. I have already set the data source to self and the thing is that when the count of the array is printed, it again prints the correct amount. I have already set the data source to self for the UITableView. Here is my code for the UITableView:

```
extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cartBrain.cartArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartcustomcell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = cartBrain.cartArray[indexPath.row].itemName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(cartBrain.cartArray[indexPath.row].itemQuantity)
        return cell
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the count of the array prints the correct amount meaning that there is data stored in it but when the View Controller is loaded, it detects that the array is empty. Thanks for the help and I'm sorry if the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Note that `prepareForRetrieval` is asynchronous, eh? So the entirety of `viewDidLoad` runs _first_, and _then_  `self.updateCart` is called. See http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ etc.

Comment: So I should add ```prepareForRetrieval()``` in front of ```super.viewDidLoad()```?

Comment: Please read the article. You need to do any follow-on from _inside the asynchronous code_.

Comment: @matt I did read through the article. Can you please post an answer on how I can change my code to make it correct? Just a note, the ```prepareForRetrieval()``` and ```updateCart()``` functions are in a struct separate from the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

After appending data to `cartArray` in `updateCart` you should `reloadData()`, like this:

```
weak var tableViewOutlet: UITableView?
func updateCart() {
        for key in keyArray {
            Database.database().reference().child("UserCart").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let itemName = value?["Item Name"] as! String
                let itemPrice = value?["Item Price"] as! Float
                let itemQuantity = value?["Item Quantity"] as! Int
                self.cartArray.append(CartData(itemName: itemName, itemQuantity: itemQuantity, itemPriceNumber: itemPrice))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableViewOutlet.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

The `updateCart` doesn't seem to have any connection to the `tableViewOutlet` so you need to pass in a reference to it in your `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cartBrain.tableViewOutlet = tableViewOutlet
    cartBrain.prepareForRetrieval()
```

Note: Since you're using a for loop to trigger the async call multiple times you can use the array count to check if all the items are appended to do the reload to avoid multiple reloads.

Comment: This solution does not work and it causes a crash in Thread 1.

Comment: What's the error you're getting when your app crashes?

Comment: This is the error: ```Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee16b3f78)```.

Comment: Ensure your `updateCart` method has access to `tableViewOutlet`. So, I've made modification to `cartBrain` and `viewDidLoad` for you implementations to work.